# Why does a pointwise convergent sequence with derivative less than 1 imply continuity of the function which it converges to?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

> Let $f_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be differentiable for each $n$ and $|f'_n(x)|\le 1$ for $n\in \Bbb N$, $x\in\Bbb R$. If the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges pointwise to a function $f$, show that $f$ is continuous.

The trouble I met is that I don't know if $$\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f_n(x)-f_n(c)}{x-c}\right|=\left|\lim_{x\to c}\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}(f_n(x)-f_n(c))}{x-c}\right|$$ so that the derivative of $f$ is less than $1$ and the existence of differentiability of $f$ implies continuity.

Since the inequality is not true in general,
can somebody tell me how to connect with $|f'_n(x)|\le1$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Use the fact that there exists $c$ such that $f_n(x)-f_n(y)=(x-y)f_n^{\prime}(c)$, hence you have  $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq [x-y|$

Comment: So this actually means that f is uniformly continuous not just continuous!? Am I correct?(I take limit at both sides of your final inequality.)

Comment: Yes, you are correct.